# Batch script to delete one subfolder and keep another while deleting all but one file in it?

Tags: batch-file

I have something that I could use help with. Let me give you the folder layout as an example:

> C:...\Logs\SubfolderA
>
> C:...\Logs\SubfolderB

Each folder contains multiple logs as text files.  What I would like to be able to do is to have a batch script which deletes the folder `SubfolderB` completely, but clears out the files in that folder `SubfolderA` except for ONE file, while preserving SubfolderA.

Alternately, I'll need another one that deletes the folder `SubfolderB` completely, then deletes everything in `SubfolderA` while keeping the folder.  Once I have an idea of how to do the one that I first mentioned, however, the next one should be easy enough for me to do.

Currently, I am just running a script from each folder that either deletes all the files in its perspective folder except for the batch file, or deletes all files except for the batch file AND the one file that I want to preserve (the `SubfolderA` batch script does this), however it would be a lot easier to kill two birds with one stone and only have to execcute one file, if that is possible.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can delete a directory (including its contents) with `rd /s /q foo`. You can delete all files in a directory using `del /f /q foo\*`.

To delete all but one file in a directory you need some criterion that applies to the one file you are keeping, and then it requires a loop over that directory's files:

```
for %%F in (foo\*) do if not "%%F"=="bar" del "%%F"
```